# grammatical function of "about to"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, adjective-phrases

> He is about to open the door.

What part of speech is "about to" in this sentence? Is it an adjective, or an adverb?

I am really confused, and somewhere I read that it is idiomatic as well.

Comment: The ***to*** is an infinitive marker for the verb *[to] **open***. As for ***about***, taking note of similar forms such as *He is **about** finished* I'd say it *adverbially* modifies the following verb form, but what do I know?

Comment: I'd say *about* is pretty clearly the ordinary preposition. The object of the preposition is the infinitival clause *to open the gate*, and the entire preposition phrase is a figurative "locative", describing the subject's location in time, exactly as in *He is on the verge of opening the gate*.

Comment: Figurative locatives insofar as they contribute to verbal aspect could be understood as verb modifiers, no? How do they differ from "He was late to arrive"?

Comment: About is an adjective meaning intending or ready. It's used  in the form be + about + to  infinitive + something as an idiom, that means someone is /was ready or intending to do something or someone is going to do something soon or something is going to happen soon.

Comment: @Khan: so you would take **about** as a predicate adjective with an infinitival clause complement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/wondering-what-the-expression-i-am-about-to)

Comment: @StoneyB: Nomenclature isn't my strong suit, but it seems pretty clear to me OP's usage is OED's definition A III 12, where the entirety of section A seems to be classed as "adverb" . What they also say there which may be relevant is: ***About** with the infinitive here **has the force of a future participle**, analogous to **going** in **to be going to**. The immediacy is usually greater with **about to** than with **going to.***

Comment: To my comment about verbal aspect above, I should insert "(albeit lexically)" before "could be understood" .

Comment: @FumbleFingers, dictionaries contradict each other: [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/about) says: *prep* 6. about to: a. on the point of; intending to: she was about to jump.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Dictionaries will blur things (e.g. parts of speech and semantic role). StoneyB is keeping it clean.

Comment: @Tromano, Yes, I think so in the same pattern as the sentence "he is ready to open the door". Most of the dictionaries say about is used as an adjective in the idiom be about to do something.

Comment: @LucianSava In order for *about* to be a preposition, it can't be removed from the sentence. It can. Also, it can be replaced with other adverbs even though it is not as much idiomatic.

Comment: @Khan Same comment as the above one. If it is an adjective as in "He is **happy** to see you", it can't be omitted. "He is to see you" and "He is happy to see you" make a world of difference.

Comment: If I compare a nurse saying *The doctor is to see you next* with *He is **[just] about** to see you [next]*, it seems to me it looks like an adverbial/adjectival usage corresponding to *He is **ready** to see you next*.

Comment: The tottering vase was about to fall. This is a locative being used in a metaphorical sense, to imply impending action. Is *impending-to-fall* the state of the vase, or is the action *fall* in a state of incipience? Can we even separate the vase from the falling?

Comment: @Rathony If you "omit" *about* you come up with a valid sentence, but it means something different.

Comment: @StoneyB . What are your fruitful remarks in answer box?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The entire phrase is "adjectival", in the sense that it behaves like a bare adjective in the same position; but this is equally true of ordinary locative prepositional phrases: *The doctor is in that room*, *The doctor is on the phone*. That doesn't make *in* and *on* adjectives.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- and note *OED*'s followup on 12 (at least in *OED 1*): **In this use it passes from the *adv.* to the *prep.***

Comment: @StoneyB: No need to convince me! I'm quite happy to accept that you and OED are *both* right - it's just that I have trouble seeing what *use* it is to come down firmly on one POS or another in this specific case. Although maybe it might help understand the obsolete usage cited by OED *It becomes every man, **about to transcribe,** or render the Works of another in his own native Tongue, neither to add any thing of his own, nor to omit of the Author's.* (when it meant *going about the business of doing*, not *soon to do*). That seems quite "prepositional" to me.

Comment: ...current OED doesn't have *In this use it passes from the adv. to the prep.* I wonder *why* they removed that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers In *OED 1* it's at the end of the entry, after the quotes, transitioning to 13.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm sure I recall you posting a link to (scanned?) OED1 in the past, but I can't find a way to access it myself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On Meta, [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/739/32)

Answer (score 2):

The word [**about**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about) is an adverb meaning:

> very close to doing something

If you omit **about**, the remaining sentence will be

> He is to open the door.

which is a so-called "be to-infinitive" construction which is mainly used to indicate a future event, intention or schedule.

"He is to open the door" doesn't indicate when he will open the door. However, if you add the adverb *about*, it indicates he will open the door very soon.

**Be about to** is a more idiomatic expression than **be soon to**.

**Edit**: If *about* is either a *preposition* or *adjective*, they cannot be omitted. If you contrast "I **was about to** call you, but something urgent came up" with "I **was to** call you, but something urgent came up", you will notice there is no big difference.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Different people have different thoughts.  It really confuses me. Still I am looking for the correct explanation.  Someone says, it is preposition.  Someone says, it is adjective.  Someone says, it is idiom. Someone says, it is adverb. Your these statements really confusing me.

Comment: @Khan, I have also looked it up in various dictionaries, but I got just an answer.  "About"is an adjective there.

Comment: I think this answer makes a good case for saying ***about*** is used adverbially in OP's context, but at the end of the day coming down solidly in favour of some specific "part of speech" here is about as useful as arguing over the "true" nature of light. At the basic level with simple examples, *particle / wave* and *adverb / preposition* may be useful distinctions to make regarding physical/syntactic phenomena, but beyond a certain point it becomes counterproductive because the classifications don't correspond to *exactly* how the "real" things function anyway.